# I am getting obscure memory leaks in my browser as I perform various ajax requests

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

After using the DevTools in Chrome and the equivalent tools in Firefox, I am having trouble finding out why a particular object is taking up lots of memory after it has gone out of scope and I would expect it to have been garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turns out I was logging a large object to the console causing the object to remain in memory.  Removing my console.log statement caused the object to be garbage collected as expected.